# Android Runtime Permissions - App Crashes when user revokes permission. How to handle it?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, permissions, crash

I have an application with many activities. When I revoke the permission the application crashes in another Activity. I tried to debug the application and catch where the activity is breaking, but when the application is killed I can´t continue to debug. My question is, is there a way to handle the permissions globally? Where in the activity I can check for permission? onStart? onCreate?Where in Activity I have to check for permission? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd check in `onResume()`, or better yet, before you use the permission you need to provide user-feedback and possibly prompt again.

Comment: "I can´t continue to debug" -- no, but you can still look at the stack trace and stuff. "Where in the activity I can check for permission?" -- sometime before you crash. :-) More specifically, you need to check the permission before you go and do something that needs the permission. Whether this is triggered by simply `onCreate()` or some specific user action (e.g., action bar item click) would depend upon your app.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have observed that when the permission is revoked (I tried both through adb and manually through settings), the application process just terminates. No crash logs in Android studio logcat, no exceptions, nothing! Probably this is what original poster meant when he said "when the application is killed I can´t continue to debug ... ". Have you noticed this behavior? Need to understand how to handle this scenario - I have a service that sends an ongoing notification which and when service terminates this way, there is no way to remove that notification from the notification panel.

Comment: @nightlytrails: "No crash logs in Android studio logcat, no exceptions, nothing!" -- that's because it is not a crash. I would expect it to behave much as if Android terminated the process due to low memory conditions. "there is no way to remove that notification from the notification panel" -- well, ideally, in this case, Android would call onDestroy() on running activities and services. But that's not guaranteed even in the low-memory case.

Comment: @CommonsWare You are right. Its not a crash; process terminates, as I said earlier. And notification part I handled as of now by having setOngoing(false). As least the user can swipe it off the screen in case the progress remains idle for long. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

First, I'd like to thanks @CommonsWare and @nightlyrails, then like to explain how I resolved the question and expect your commentaries.

in method onCreate() checked if the savedInstanceBundle is null. If it is null the activity is just starting and everything is ok.
If the savedInstanceBundle is not null, I asked for permissions.

By doing this, I could prevent application from crash, everytime I revoked the permissions.

One more time, thanks for the tips.

Comment: Would you be able to show the sample code by any chance ?